# Running Query twice in case of failure

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I always check if MySQL Queries are successful and run them again if not (instead of displaying or logging errors etc)

Sometimes for important queries, i even put them in a limited `While` loop to try for 5-10 times in case of failure

For Example:

```
$update = $db->update("table", ["today" => $date]]);

if ($update === FALSE OR $affected_rows < 1)
{
    // Optional sleep(1);
    $update = $db->update("table", ["today" => $date]]);
}

if ($update === FALSE OR $affected_rows < 1)
{
    // Now log if the second try failed too...
}
```

But today I was thinking if this is a right thing to do, and maybe even there is already a function to retry instead of typing the same query twice in the code (so if we change one We have to remember to change the other)

### My Questions Are

1. Is this a right thing to do? any downsides? (i mean it doesn't run twice if it is successful)
2. Is there a simpler way to do this (not using the same code twice)? I'm Copy-Pasting the same query twice, and if I change the first and forget to change the second it can be dangerous (I'm using Meedo which is a PDO wrapper)

`P.S. I know the second won't work if the MySQL is down etc, i do it for temporary Failed attempts or Aborts or anything else that may not happen on the second try)`

Comment: I don't think it's right. If server is down, a consecutive query will fail too. You better tell the user to try later.

Comment: now this i have never heard

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Yes, but i've tried a query loop on local machine sometimes a query fails but the next (immediate) one doesn't, also i sometimes add sleep() to it, like i added to my question.

Comment: Maybe too much traffic may cause it. Just remember your users are waiting for the resulting page, consecutive querys may slow down a lot the response time and they may leave you.

Comment: "Insanity is repeating the same mistakes and expecting different results" this is all your doing. I will be incredibly rare that this ever works

Comment: why stop at two? for that matter, consider entering a potentially endless while loop (i am just kidding)

Comment: I'm glad i asked it here to know it's mistake, i can't use transactions but the reason is out of this question, thank you all for good points

Comment: Occasionally it is valid to retry a query, but it of course depends on the error returned by the one that failed.

Comment: @pala_ Could you please give an example of error, in which retrying a query is valid?

Comment: Lock contention deadlocks spring to mind. Not generally an issue unless you're running on a cluster.  Generally, any transaction rollback caused by the activities of another transaction. But syntax errors, server issues, there's no point retrying those

Comment: I think there are some valid reasons (timeout , etc) to retry a query especially you know the reason of failure. However, you may want to sleep a random period of time before you retry. If you get timeout because your database is busy , retrying continuously may just make things worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you are pursuing a strategy here that is "broken by-design."  Instead of figuring out *why* the previous attempt did not succeed, you are (blindly ...) "just trying it again."  (And, apparently, in the ivory-tower of your "development environment," it has not *[yet(!)]* "failed *twice!"*  But, sooner or sooner, it will.)

You need to "get to the **bottom** of this, once and for all."

*Why(?!)* is the query failing on its first attempt?  Is there any plausible reason why it should?  *(I see none ...)*  Therefore, it is not good-enough to "merely make the problem (seem to) 'go away.'"  You have to *solve* it.

When you are "updating things" in SQL, in a shared database, you ordinarily need to use "Transactions."  (And, in the MySQL environment, that means that you must use *"InnoDB"* tables.)  You `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then you make your series of updates (or inserts, deletes, whatever ...), then you either `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: Thank you Mike, sadly i can't use Transactions but reason is out of this question so i guess i have to ask another, it was the main reason i came with this (wrong) idea

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not right way to implement. Just look for errors, then show error message and ask user to re-try in a few seconds/minutes.
2. Maybe you are looking for [Transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)

Answer (score 1):

A QUOTE from php:

> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value
>   is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that
>   mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows
>   matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the
>   query.