# How to handle query errors safely when working with two different databases at the same time (first one is MyISAM)

Tags: php, mysql, database

### The long explanation

I have to write an extension for a closed-source (Ioncubed!) program which uses MyISAM storage (MySQL) on a different database of itself (other than my Database)

> I chose InnoDB for my extension's database and created new database for my extension, But I can change my database storage to MyISAM, I can also add my database tables to that program's instead of creating a new database (No limits on my side)

At some point I have to INSERT `3 rows` to `2 different tables` on this Closed-source program's (MyISAM) database,

I do so by 2 queries (a Single row INSERT and a Double row INSERT)

```
$insert1 = $db->insert("table_1", ["name" => "$value"]);

$insert2 = $db->insert("table_2", ["name" => "$value"],["name" => "$value"]);
```

Then update my database too, this is after successful insert of the above

```
if ($insert1 !== FALSE && $insert2 !== FALSE){
    $db->update("my_table", ["name" => "$new_value"]);
}
```

Now that i can't use database Transactions (being MyISAM and 2 different databases), What can i do to make sure `all of them are successful` and if not, `none of them should be inserted`.

It is very sensitive data, specially on closed-source program's side.

I was thinking of manually checking and deleting the previously inserted row (in case of failure) seems not a good idea,

because too many inserts/updates queries are running and as i know inserted ROW ID cannot be completely trusted outside a database transaction

I've done crazy things like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518605/running-query-twice-in-case-of-failure) , so to avoid more mistakes i had to ask here.

### The short Question

I am asking if there is a simple way to handle sensitive MySQL query failures/errors when using 2 different databases and the first one is MyISAM.

Comment: If you can't use transactions, there's no way to ensure that requirement reliably. That's the whole reason transactions were invented: it's not possible to do it outside the DBMS.

Comment: Why does it matter how many databases you're using? You'd have the same problem with a single database, as long as any of the tables use MyISAM.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't sure if it matters, so I just pointed that i have no limits on my side i can have another db, or use the same.

Comment: It just sounds like you think the engine is an attribute of the database. It's a per-table setting.